# Disable whole page scrolling in ipad using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am using jquery mobile .i Have one header and dynamically created table .But when i check my code on browser it working fine but when i check on ipad simulator Whole page is scrolling with header .How to prevent header scrolling in Ipad .I need only table view scroll with fixed height .Here is my code in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/Q9QmF/1/

```
    var content = "<table>";
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            content += '<tr class="row" id="' + i + '"><td>' + 'result ' + i + '</td></tr>';
        }
        content += "</table>"
        $('#here_table').append(content);


        $(".row").click(function() {
            alert(this.id);
        });
```

Comment: When i used different way to create table .While scrolling the table view it also click row .can you please tell me how to remove click event while scrolling ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an ID to your header bar and try this script.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#your_header").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
});
```